# Steps of changing from 32-bit OS to 64-bit and changing RAM?

Tags: memory, bios, operating-systems

My laptop is Lenovo T400, whose CPU is 64-bit and RAM is 1x2GB. When I bought it, it already had 32-bit Windows 7. Then I partition the hard drive and install 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7.

Now I am going to reintall the Ubuntu part from 32-bit 12.04 to 64-bit (possibly the latest version), while still keeping 32-bit Windows 7.

I am also going to change my RAM from 1x2GB to 2x4GB.

1. I heard that I have to make some change in BIOS (from a commend on
   my another post, which has now been deleted). Do you know what
   change it is? Is it for reinstalation of Ubuntu from 32-bit to
   64-bit, or for changing RAM from 1x2GB to 2x4GB?
2. What is the order of the following steps: change BIOS, reinstall
   Ubuntu from 32-bit to 64-bit, change RAM from 1x2GB to 2x4GB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No steps required really. I would load the system with the memory and then go ahead with the Ubuntu install. Keep in mind that Win 7 and Ubuntu 32 bit will load quite happily with 8 gigs of memory but at the most will only be able to access 4 gigs tops.

Consider upgrading your Win 7 to a 64 bit version too - just sounds like a waste to have a 32 bit OS on an 8 gig system.

Comment: Thanks! (1) Do I need to change something in BIOS? (2) Do I have to buy 64-bit Win 7 for upgrading it from 32 bit to 64 bit?

Comment: No changes in BIOS and you'll have to do a custom reinstall of Windows 7 64 bit using a retail cd.

Comment: If my friend has a 64-bit Windows 7 CD, can I use his CD on my laptop?

Comment: Yes, just make sure to use your old 32 bit product key if you don't plan on installing the copy on another computer. And make sure its not an OEM disc either.

Comment: Where to find my old 32 bit product key? My Win 7 32-bit comes with my laptop. I don't have a CD of Win 7 32-bit.

Comment: It should be on a sticker stuck to the side of the laptop/case. If there isn't a sticker you can use a tool like magic jelly bean key finder to extract the key from the registry

Answer (score 1):

No Bios changes required. simply goahead. probably this is the interface you're going to work with

[image]

Just Customize the existing ubuntu partition(meaning just delete and create again)

then just press next, next, next and you're there. you don't need to worry about bootloaders ubuntu GRUB will Take care of that. by the time you boot that will show you GRUB. hope you're familiar with that. in case any problem with boot order or GRUB just install EasyBCD http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/

this allows you to Edit the boot order and more other things as well